# solve system of equations to get service demands from a mixture

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have an equation of the form
U=T1×S1+T2×S2+T3×S3
where U = utilization
Ti = throughput of i
Si = service time of i
constraint, S1+S2+S3≤R where R is response time U,T1,T2,T3,S1,S2,S3 are single values I know the value of U,Ti and R. From this how will I determine S1,S2,S3.

Please suggest me  any mathematical method using which I can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

To transform the inequality into an equality you could add a non negative slack variable to the left hand side of the constraint.

You should expect to get many solutions to this, because you have 2 equations and 3 variables (+1slack).

Comment: could u explain with an example